# How to check if two selects return the same ids

Tags: sql

Suppose, we have query like this:

```
SELECT
1
FROM DUAL WHERE  
(SELECT id FROM table_1 t1 WHERE /*conditions*/)
IN
(SELECT id FROM table_1 t2 WHERE /*conditions*/)
```

I want to check if first query
`SELECT id FROM table_1 t1 WHERE /*conditions*/`
returns the same ids like the second query.
Of course this query (`IN` statement) doesn't work.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return everything from the first set that is not also contained in the second set, or NULL if the second set contains every element of the first set:

```
SELECT id FROM table_1 t1 WHERE /*conditions*/
EXCEPT
SELECT id FROM table_1 t2 WHERE /*conditions*/
```

If the second set contains additional elements not in the first set, they are not part of the result set.

On a Venn diagram, `EXCEPT` returns only what is contained in the first circle that isn't overlapped by the second circle, and doesn't include anything at all from the second circle.

Comment: Don't you need to do EXCEPT ALL to handle duplicates correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT id FROM table_1 t1 WHERE /*conditions1*/ and id not in (SELECT id FROM table_1 t2 WHERE /*conditions2*/)
union 
SELECT id FROM table_1 t1 WHERE /*conditions2*/ and id not in (SELECT id FROM table_1 t2 WHERE /*conditions1*/)
```

If both queries gives you the same id's the result should be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EXCEPT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx).

> EXCEPT returns distinct rows from the left input query that aren’t
>   output by the right input query.

---

`EXCEPT` sample in your case:

```
SELECT id 
FROM   table_1 AS t1 
WHERE /*conditions*/
EXCEPT
SELECT id 
FROM   table_1 AS t2 
WHERE /*conditions*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative method that used `Full Join` *in tsql*:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN isnull(Count(*), 0) > 1 then 1 else 0 end as result
FROM    (SELECT t1.id as t1_id, t2.id as t2_id FROM 
            (SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE /*conditions*/) As t1 
            Full Outer Join 
            (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE /*conditions*/) As t2 
    On t1.id = t2.id
    ) As ft
WHERE ft.t1_id is null or ft.t2_id is null
```

And I think this can marked as a stupid way.

Answer (score 0):

To check if both sets contain the EXACT same ids, you could verify that the following query returns nothing :

```sql
(
    select id from table_1 t1 where /*conditions*/
    EXCEPT
    select id from table_1 t2 where /*conditions*/
)
UNION ALL
(
    select id from table_1 t2 where /*conditions*/
    EXCEPT
    select id from table_1 t1 where /*conditions*/
)
```

The first parenthesis returns ids from t1 that aren't in t2, and the second returns ids from t2 that aren't in t1.

In this case :

- EXCEPT allows you to verify that the first set is contained in the second
- UNION ALL allows you to merge both differences